# Measure time Spark operations (loading, processing, writing)

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

I have written some code in PySpark to load some data from MongoDB to a Spark dataframe, apply some filters, process the data (using a RDD) and then write back the result to MongoDB.

```
# 1) Load the data
df_initial  = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").options().schema(schema).load() #df_initial is a Spark dataframe
df_filtered = df_initial.filter(...)

# 2) Process the data
rdd_to_process = df_filtered.rdd
processed_rdd = rdd_to_process.mapPartitions(lambda iterator: process_data(iterator))

# 3) Create a dataframe from the RDD
df_final = spark.createDataFrame(processed_rdd, schema)
df_to_write = df_final.select(...)

# 4) Write the dataframe to MongoDB
df_to_write.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").mode("append").save()
```

I would like to measure the time each part takes (loading the data, processing the RDD, creating the dataframe, and writing back data).

I tried to put timers between each part but from what I understood all the Spark operations are lazy so everything is executed in the last line.

Is there a way to measure the time spent by each part so that I can identify bottlenecks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark can inline some operations, especially if you use Dataframe API. That's why you cannot get execution statistics of "code parts", but only for different stages.

There is not an easy way to get these information from the context directly, but [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) presents a lot information you may use. For example to get time spent in each stage you can use the following instructions:

```
import datetime
import requests
parse_datetime = lambda date: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fGMT")
dates_interval = lambda dt1, dt2: parse_datetime(dt2) - parse_datetime(dt1)

app_id = spark.sparkContext.applicationId
data = requests.get(spark.sparkContext.uiWebUrl + "/api/v1/applications/" + app_id + "/stages").json()

for stage in data:
    stage_time = dates_interval(stage['submissionTime'], stage['completionTime']).total_seconds()
    print("Stage {} took {}s (tasks: {})".format(stage['stageId'], stage_time, stage['numCompleteTasks']))
```

Example output looks like this:

```
Stage 4 took 0.067s (tasks: 1)
Stage 3 took 0.53s (tasks: 1)
Stage 2 took 1.592s (tasks: 595)
Stage 1 took 0.363s (tasks: 1)
Stage 0 took 2.367s (tasks: 595)
```

But then it's your job to identify what are the stages responsible for operations you want to measure.